# JavaScript - How to Change innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I am arguing the values of input DOM elements with JavaScript functions.

This simple chemistry app has two input DOM elements which can hold two values.

If the document.getElementById("Hydrogen").value is = 2 
 and the
 document.getElementById("Oxygen").value is = 1,
 then the
 document.getElementById("Molecule").innerHTML should = "WATER".

Please look at the JavaScript.

Why is the"Molecule()" function not working?

-- Thanks

```
<!doctype> <html> 

<head>

<!-- JavaScript (Button Controls) -->

<script>

function deleteHydrogen() { document.getElementById("Hydrogen").value--;}

function addHydrogen() {document.getElementById("Hydrogen").value++ ;}

function deleteCarbon() { document.getElementById("Carbon").value--; }

function addCarbon() { document.getElementById("Carbon").value++;}

function deleteOxygen() {document.getElementById("Oxygen").value--; }

function addOxygen() { document.getElementById("Oxygen").value++;}

function Molecule() { 
    if ((document.getElementById("Hydrogen").value=="2") &&   
(document.getElementById("Oxygen").value=="1")) 
    {document.getElementById("Molecule").innerHTML="WATER"; } }

</script>
</head>
```

```
<body onload="Molecule()">

<input type="text" id="Hydrogen" style="width:160px; height:90px; font- 
size:50px; text-align:center;" value="0" />

<input type="text" id="Carbon" style="width:160px; height:90px; font-
size:50px; text-align:center;" value="0" />

<input type="text" id="Oxygen" style="width:160px; height:90px; font- 
 size:50px; text-align:center;" value="0" />


<img  id="delete_H" src="delete_H.png" style="width:80px; height:80px;"  
 onmousedown="deleteHydrogen()"/>  

<img id="add_H" src="add_H.png" style="width:80px; height:80px;"  
 onmousedown="addHydrogen()" />

<img  id="delete_C" src="delete_C.png" style="width:80px; height:80px;"   
 onmousedown="deleteCarbon()"/>  

<img id="add_C" src="add_C.png" style="width:80px;   
 height:80px;"onmousedown="addCarbon()"/>

<img  id="delete_O" src="delete_O.png" style="width:80px; height:80px;"   
 onmousedown="deleteOxygen()"/>  

<img id="add_O" src="add_O.png" style="width:80px; height:80px;"   
 onmousedown="addOxygen()"/>


<p id="Molecule" style="width:510px; height:80px; font-size:50px; 
color:white; text-align:center; background:gray;">  molecule </p>


</body> </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the `Molecule` method only runs once when the page loads (when all the values are null).

```
onload="Molecule()"
```

If you want the page to respond to user input you need to add event listeners to the `input` fields that are part of the calculation. Try removing the `onload` event listener and adding `onclick="Molecule()"` to your `Hydrogen` and `Oxygen` `input` elements.

Comment: Even better, call `Molecule()` at the end of every other function. (It seems like that's the primary method for changing state)